# Stream Kinect RGB or Depth Camera to Internet

Tags: iis, iis-7, video-streaming, video-capture, kinect

Im wanting to stream the feed that comes out of the kinect RGB or depth camera to my website. Im wondering whether this is possible? And also can someone advise me on how to start going about this or if any examples of this exist? We are developing on windows with visual studio and the kinect sdk (hopefully deploying the live stream via IIS 7).

Hoping to stay away from commerical packages as the end product will be opensource.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Kinect to HTML5 interaction was demo'ed at REMIX Australia this year. The way it had been set-up was by a Windows Service, exposing a WCF end-point that then allows the Javascript to talk back to the Kinect. This worked well in a Kinect <-> Server <-> Client scenario - so you may be able to take this approach and use some kind of TCP stream into a rich media application such as Flash or Silverlight. If you want to use live stream, I would look into taking the incoming RGB/depth video frames and writing them back to the IIS7 using API's. This could be housed in an application or service - either way you'll need to proxy the Kinect through a custom application as Windows doesn't see it as a video device.
If you want to use the users Kinect (i.e. the one on their computer, and not attachted or proxied through your webserver) you could use Silverlight. Silverlight when run with elevated permissions (out of the browser) allows you to pinvoke a COM object - which means you'll be able to access the local Kinect sensors. You can then either render the UI using Silverlight directly, or create a Javascript inter-op that allows Silverlight to access the Kinect and pass the data into Javascript on the client side. The only down side of this is the user will need the Kinect for Windows SDK installed on their machine (until a redistributable version is available).

Answer (score 0):

From: https://groups.google.com/group/openkinect/browse_thread/thread/e8adfb5695bd1e56#

> [Intrael](http://www.intrael.com/) is a small app server that provides a solid HTTP
>   interface to the MS kinect. It processes the depth data coming from
>   the device, tracks objects and provides several of their properties to
>   network clients. The raw outputs from the cameras are also provided as
>   JPEG images or MJPEG video streams. Using nothing more than plain
>   AJAX, computer vision can now be performed directly and efficiently in
>   the browser. From smart security cameras to all kinds of interactive
>   surfaces, a multitude of new possibilities opens up for web
>   development. The input process itself becomes an art. The code is very
>   efficient, highly portable and licenced as free software (GPL). Visit
>   http://www.intrael.com for details, source and binaries for your
>   platform.

Comment: Hi mankoff, thanks for your response. I think you helped my out on my other post. The only issue is I have developed my depth and camera mapping using the Windows Kinect Sdk, and it doesnt seem that intrael will play to well with the Windows Kinect Sdk. Any ideas on how to integrate something like this with the win kinect sdk (or if there is something out there that would do the same thing)?